# What's the difference between [Something] and [SomethingAttribute]

Tags: c#, .net-attributes

This has probably been already asked but it's hard to search for.

What is the difference between `[Something]` and `[SomethingAttribute]`?

Both of the following compile:

```c#
[DefaultValue(false)]
public bool Something { get; set; }
```

```c#
[DefaultValueAttribute(false)]
public bool SomethingElse { get; set; }
```

Are there any differences between these apart from their appearance?  What's the general guideline on their use?

Comment: No difference; prefer `[DefaultValue(false)]`.

Comment: The better question is why does the "xxxAttribute" exist at all :-).

Comment: I suppose it would matter for `DefaultValue` or `DefaultValueAttributeAttribute` types ..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no functional difference. `[Something]` is just shorthand syntax for `[SomethingAttribute]`.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfz783fz(v=vs.110).aspx):

> By convention, all attribute names end with Attribute. However,
>   several languages that target the runtime, such as Visual Basic and
>   C#, do not require you to specify the full name of an attribute. For
>   example, if you want to initialize System.ObsoleteAttribute, you only
>   need to reference it as Obsolete.

Answer (score 6):

In **most** cases they are the same. As already said you can typically use them interchangeable *except* when you have both `DefaultValue` and `DefaultValueAttribute` defined. You can use both of these without ambiguity errors by using the verbatim identifier (`@`).

The C#LS section 17.2 makes this more clear:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
public class X: Attribute {}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
public class XAttribute: Attribute {}

[X] // Error: ambiguity
class Class1 {}

[XAttribute] // Refers to XAttribute
class Class2 {}

[@X] // Refers to X
class Class3 {}

[@XAttribute] // Refers to XAttribute
class Class4 {}
```

This refers to the actual usage of the attribute. Of course if you require use of the type name such as when using `typeof` or reflection, you'll need to use the actual name you gave the type.

Answer (score 2):

Both are same in the context where attribute declaration goes. Former is shorter form of latter. But it does makes the difference inside a method.

For example if you say `typeof(DefaultValue)` in some method, that won't compile. You'll have to say `typeof(DefaultValueAttribute)` instead.

```
private void DoSomething()
{
    var type = typeof(DefaultValue);//Won't compile
    var type2 = typeof(DefaultValueAttribute);//Does compile
}
```

Comment: It would be better if the downvoter can point what's wrong with the answer.

Comment: There was nothing wrong. I think the down voter did not know what you're talking about since its clearly a good answer

Comment: +1 You make a good point. Outside of the declarative attribute context, you cannot just drop "Attribute" from the end.